# Android Multipart Entity Upload

Tags: android, httpresponse

I am trying to upload `StringBody` using `Multipart Entity` in Android.
I am getting the following response from the server

```
--4-9m14lHqfFFgoZHvYFlrRKt2-aPnozj4d Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image" Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

hiiiii
--4-9m14lHqfFFgoZHvYFlrRKt2-aPnozj4d
```

I want to remove the content disposition from the response message.
How can I remove it?
Is it a server side issue or do we need to do something on the Android side?

Comment: mostly, its server side issue..

Comment: That is a strange response as it is part of the text the client did sent. What is the server supposed to reply instead? It makes no sense to me to remove content disposition fromn that response as the response looks completely wrong.